# Why does Artifactory require an explicit artifact for some Ivy dependencies

Tags: ivy, artifactory

I have an Artifactory server that I use to resolve Ivy dependencies. When I want to add a dependency to my `ivy.xml`, I sometimes have to add an explicit nested `<artifact>` tag, and I don't understand why.

**Example A:**

```
<dependency org="com.google" name="guava" rev="[7,)" conf="compile,runtime" />
```

**Example B**

```
<dependency org="com.twelvemonkeys.common" name="common-image" rev="3.0.1" conf="compile,runtime">
  <artifact name="common-image" ext="jar"/>
</dependency>
```

Looking at the cached dependencies in the Artifactory tree view, there's nothing that indicates that the last example should need extra info to resolve the dependency, but Artifactory suggests it itself, and the resolution doesn't work without out.

I'm using Ivy against a repository with Maven layout. My settings where generated by Artifactory and look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-settings>
  <settings defaultResolver="main" />
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="main">
      <ibiblio 
        name="public" 
        m2compatible="true" 
        root="http://example.org/artifactory/remote-repos" />
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivy-settings>
```

Why does Artifactory require an explicit artifact for some Ivy dependencies and not for others?

***Edit 20151005: Added Ivy settings example***

Answer (score 1):

The tool performing the dependency resolution is the Ivy client and not Artifactory.
Based on the dependency deceleration the Ivy [resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html) decides which artifact to request from the repository (in your case it is Artifactory).
The [artifact](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/ivyfile/dependency-artifact.html) feature provides more control on a dependency for which you do not control its ivy file.
It enables to specify the artifacts required, if the dependency has no ivy file.
For more information about the artifact feature and when it should be used consult the Ivy [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/ivyfile/dependency-artifact.html).

Comment: I updated the question text with more details. As I understand your answer, the "artifact" element is necessary when there is no ivy settings for the dependency in the repository? AFAICT, neither guava or common-image have Ivy config, and yet for the first one I don't need the artifact-tag.

What am I missing?